# smartgwt calendar getdaybodyhtml issue

Tags: firefox, calendar, smartgwt

I have a issue with the smartgwt calendar tool, I've customized it to assign special icon flags certain days in the month through the protected method getdaybodyhtml() of the class calendar, everything works fine except for one thing when I display the calendar on  chrome(all versions) IE(7,8,9) and FF(till 14.0.1), but when I display the calendar on FF(between 15 to 19) this flags icons aren't displayed. I've made a follow to the code and I found that the html code that I defined there in the getdaybodyhtml() method is not printed.

I was looking on the smartgwt for any issue like that but i don't found anything related.
Any help would be received.
(sorry if my english is not so good, is my second language)

Here is the piece of code:

```
private Calendar calendar = new Calendar(){
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected String getDayBodyHTML(Date date, CalendarEvent[] events, Calendar calendar, int rowNum, int colNum) {
        String value = defaultMessage != null ? defaultMessage : date.getDate()+"";
        // The "events" are the events of the day
        List<CalendarEvent> calendarEvents =  new ArrayList<CalendarEvent>(Arrays.asList(events));
        if(calendarEvents != null && calendarEvents.size() > 0) {
            // Removing the tooltip and the excluded colours
            removeTooltipsFromCalendar(calendar,date);
            removeExcludedColoursFromCalendar(calendarEvents);
            if(calendarEvents.size() == 1){
                // Description contains the colour
                String colour = calendarEvents.get(0).getDescription();
                value = imgHTML(COASTAL_IMAGES_DIR+colour+COASTAL_IMAGE_SUFFIX, colourWidth, colourHeight, "images", "class='handCursor'", null);
            }else if(calendarEvents.size() > 1){
                // Might have two vessels going to the same port in the same day
                Set<String> colours = new HashSet<String>();
                for(CalendarEvent event : calendarEvents){
                    // Description contains the colour
                    colours.add(event.getDescription());
                }
                int numberOfPorts = colours.size();
                for(String colour : colours){
                    value += "<div>";
                    value += imgHTML(COASTAL_IMAGES_DIR+colour+COASTAL_IMAGE_SUFFIX, colourWidth, colourHeight/numberOfPorts, "images", "class='handCursor'", null);
                    value += "</div>";
                }
            }else{
                value = defaultMessage != null ? defaultMessage : date.getDate()+"";
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
};
```

PD: In all the versions of chrome and IE the piece of code:

```
value += "<div>";
                value += imgHTML(COASTAL_IMAGES_DIR+colour+COASTAL_IMAGE_SUFFIX, colourWidth, colourHeight/numberOfPorts, "images", "class='handCursor'", null);
                value += "</div>";
```

is printed ok, in fire fox till the 14 version it's printed ok, but in ff from 15 to 19 not prints the "div" and the "image". I already see the code throw firebug and the div just not apear in that firefox version(15-19).

PD: it doesn't work on last update of IE 10 too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see icons in following [sample in SmartGWT showcase](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#compact_calendar_category).

I'm able to see icons in above sample for April 2, April 3, April 4 and April 5 as of March 31.
CalendarEvent instances used in this sample are created for 2, 3, 4 and 5 days ahead of current date.

I'm using FireFox 19.0.2

Comment: yes, I'm able to see that icons on different versions of FF but in my app I can't see them.

Comment: @dakairus May be your image locations are incorrect. Add your getDayBodyHTML() method code to the question. Install [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) and check requests in Net tab to see if they succeed or fail for images.

Comment: I already seek throw firebug with no answer for the problem. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the issue. I don't know why but in the resent versions of Firefox, after 14 version, the gwt calendar(v 2.1) is repeating the printing of the calendar twice automatically, so when it prints the second time, it did it without the images inside the day bodies.

Solution: manually creation of code to stop the twice printing.